# JPA Connection for eclipselink as a provider and oracle as a database

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to execute simple JPA mapping using EclipseLink as jpa provider.

```
[![Persistence and Project Structure][1]][1]
```

above image explains the project structure and persistence.xml.
above mentioned database details, i have checked in oracle toad. I am able to access specified schema as shown below.

```
[![opening database connection ][2]][2]
```

in above image, you could see the connection.

```
following is the POJO
```

it is a simple pojo class which has one field which i defined as a primary key and other fields.

```
package com.sun.arise;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;




@Entity
@Table(name="Sun")
public class Sun {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int sunid;

  @Column(name="DAY")
private String day;

  @Column(name="MONTH")
private String month;


  public String getDay() {
  return day;
  }


  public void setDay(String day) {
  this.day = day;
  }


  public String getMonth() {
  return month;
  }


  public void setMonth(String month) {
  this.month = month;
  }


public int getSunId()
{
  return sunid;
}


@Override
public String toString()
{
  return getSunId()+"\n"+getDay()+"\n"+getMonth();
}
}
```

to persist above pojo i wrote following class

```
package com.sun.sunset;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


import com.sun.arise.Sun;


public class TestSun {

public static void main(String args[])
{
  String persistenceUnitName="myAttemptAtJPA";
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  Sun z = new Sun();
  z.setDay("Saturday");
  z.setMonth("January");

  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.persist(z);
  em.getTransaction().commit();

}
}
```

after executing i am getting following errors
i am not sure error is because it is not able to find persistence.xml in META-INF folder.  it is not able to find url and  driver.

```
[EL Fine]: server: 2016-06-14 17:02:31.478--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Configured server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-06-14 17:02:31.592--ServerSession(19166103)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class com.sun.arise.Sun] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-06-14 17:02:31.612--ServerSession(19166103)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class com.sun.arise.Sun] is being defaulted to: Sun.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-06-14 17:02:31.627--ServerSession(19166103)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [sunid] is being defaulted to: SUNID.
[EL Info]: 2016-06-14 17:02:31.65--ServerSession(19166103)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2016-06-14 17:02:31.652--ServerSession(19166103)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
  at com.sun.sunset.TestSun.main(TestSun.java:15)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
  at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.unableToAcquireConnectionFromDriverException(DatabaseException.java:383)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:91)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:207)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:760)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
  ... 5 more
```

please let me know if any more information is required. 
thanks

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD0Ru.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXEN0.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such persistence properties `javax.persistence.driver`, etc.

They are

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver
javax.persistence.jdbc.user
```

etc